# Modificar fichero xml en tema hijo Wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theme

He creado un tema hijo en Wordpress y desearía modificar un ficheros *.xml que tengo en el tema padre. ¿Cómo puedo encolar este tipo de ficheros en el tema hijo para poder realizar la modificaciones que necesito?

Un saludo y muchas gracias

He estado investigando y finalmente no veo realacionado este fichero XML con el resto de ficheros php. Creo que el XML es generado como fichero de exportación de datos  que luego puedo importar a un theme.

Bueno, la razon de todo es por que necesito cambiar el front-page, puesto que en lugar de la imagen que toma de la galería de wordpress, quiero que esto sea un video incrustado. Estoy trabajando con un child theme y revisando con el desarrollador web de Chrome, veo que la línea de código que inserta la imagen es la siguiente:

```
<img src="http://localhost/Cover/wp- 
content/uploads/2018/01/Fondo_web_freepik.com_.jpg" alt="Fondo_web" 
draggable="false">
```

El problema es que no consigo localizar este código entre los ficheros php del theme para poder modificarlo. He usado un software para buscar cadenas de texto en ficheros (TextCrawler) y no consigo encontrarlo.
¿Me podrían indicar alguna solución al respecto?

Saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: Necesitas localizar el sitio o sitios en dónde se usa dicho fichero (includes, loads, ajax, etc...), entonces duplicas la estructura de todos esos ficheros más el propio xml y en tu theme hijo, modificas todas las llamadas (rutas al fichero xml) hacía tu fichero .xml del theme hijo, para que esto funcione, el theme original debe de haber seguido unas reglas usando por ejemplo, function_exists de php para declarar las funciones, así priorizan las tuyas y de alguna manera estás aplicando un override.

Comment: que sería `encolar`, leerlos por código en tu theme hijo ?  la modificación es permanente o temporal durante el uso del theme?